# SpringBoot JPA HQL LIKE query is not working after upgrade to Spring-boot 3.1.0, JDK17 from Spring boot 3.0.6

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Spring Boot 3.1.0 JPA HQL LIKE query is not working after upgrade to **Spring-boot 3.1.0, JDK17** from **Spring boot 3.0.6**

JPA Like query with named parameters was working fine before upgrade.
But after upgrading to SpringBoot 3.1.0 getting runtime error.
We get this error, when we use like operator with % symbol on string column for 'like' condition.

We can reproduce the issue by mentioning the DEBUG log level for package "org.hibernate.orm.query.hql" in application.properties file.

logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.query.hql=DEBUG

**Note: This query JPA HQL query was working fine using older versions of Spring boot (< 3.0.6). It is upgrade issue.**

JPA HQL query example using @Query annotation.

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Movie m WHERE m.title LIKE %:title%")
List<Movie> searchByTitleLike(@Param("title") String title);
```

Error message/Stack Trace:

```
Caused by: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '''
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2750)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2671)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2625)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:4143)
    at org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLocationAwareLogger.doLogf(Slf4jLocationAwareLogger.java:81)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.logf(Logger.java:2445)
    at org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger.debugf(DelegatingBasicLogger.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.lambda$interpretHql$2(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:744)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.interpretHql(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:741)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:786)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:704)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:120)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy153.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:94)
    ... 96 more
```

Comment: References:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-like-queries
Refer Section 4.1, 4.2

Answer (score 1):

**Given this HQL query**

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Movie m WHERE m.title LIKE %:title%")
```

SpringBoot 3.0.7 Converted HQL Query for printing HQL Query in Logs:

```
SELECT m FROM Movie m WHERE m.title LIKE :title
```

Note: here Spring Boot 3.0.7 library is stripping of % symbol before printing to logs.

SpringBoot 3.1.0 Converted HQL Query for printing HQL query in Logs:

```
SELECT m 
FROM Movie m 
WHERE m.title LIKE CONCAT('%', :title, '%')
```

But % symbol is used as format specifier when format() method is called before printing to logs. Refer Java.util.Formatter.format() method.

Single % symbol in string argument to format() method throws conversion exception.

**Workarounds**

**Option #1**

Add the INFO log level to package 'org.hibernate.orm.query.hql' in the application.properties file to avoid the exception on the application start up during bean creation time.

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.query.hql=INFO
```

**Option #2**

Escape the % symbol in the given HQL query with another % symbol as shown below to avoid the exception on the application start up during bean creation time.

```
SELECT m 
FROM Movie m 
WHERE m.title LIKE CONCAT('%%', :title, '%%')
```

Looks like it is bug in the Spring Boot 3.1.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

**How i know % is a special character in a format string that indicates that a format specifier follows.**

Try it:

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Movie m WHERE m.title LIKE :title")
List<Movie> searchByTitleLike(@Param("title") String title);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Yes, the above query without % symbol is working.
However, our objective is to use "%title%" query. So that, query search for a sub-string title containing in the db column.
It is not working with %title% in the HQL query

Comment: What if you will try this approach 'percent signs must be used outside the query string, unlike traditional SQL.' . @Query("SELECT m FROM Movie m WHERE m.title LIKE ':percent:title:percent'")
List<Movie> searchByTitleLike(@Param("title") String title, @Param("percent") String percentage);

Comment: But this was working fine in the previous Spring Boot Verison 3.0.6. Given the same 

HQL Query

@Query("SELECT m FROM Movie m WHERE m.title LIKE %:title%")
List<Movie> searchByTitleLike(@Param("title") String title);

There is nothing wrong in the HQL query.
This is a SpringBoot Upgrade issue.

Answer (score 0):

The given issue is fixed in the latest version of Spring Boot 3.1.2 without doing any code changes for like query.

Answer (score 0):

It still not working in Spring Boot 3.2.0 version. I hadn't this problem in 2.7.5 version.

If somebody has problem with criteriaBuilder problem, I fixed this with adding third parameter to `criteriaBuilder.like(foo, foo, '/')`

Now hibernate adds `ESCAPE` to `like` clause